# Who was the King of Cheshbon (in the Torah)?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, historical-figures, malchut-royalty, bamidbar-numbers-book-of

Who was the king of Cheshbon, mentioned in Bamidbar?

Comment: Not to be confused with the [Mathemagician, King of Digitopolis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Phantom_Tollbooth#Main_characters)

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you mean the king of Cheshbon?

Cheshbon was the capital city of Sichon, king of the Amorites ("Emorim").  The Jews conquered it.

See [Numbers 21:21--27](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=4&CHAPTER=21):

> Israel sent emissaries to Sichon king
>   of the Amorites ... Sichon, however,
>   did not let Israel pass through his
>   territories. Instead, Sichon mustered
>   up all his people, and went out to
>   confront Israel in the desert. When he
>   came to Yahatz, he attacked Israel.
>   ... Israel thus took all these cities.
>   They [later] settled in Cheshbon and
>   all its tributary towns, all the
>   Amorite cities. ... **Cheshbon was the
>   capital of Sichon king of the
>   Amorites.**  ... The minstrels
>   therefore say: Come to Cheshbon!  Let
>   Sichon's city be built and
>   established!

The verses indicate that the Amorites conquered land from the Moabites; some commentaries read these verses as saying that Cheshbon had always been Amorite ("let Sichon's city be built and established!"); others read it that Cheshbon was also part of the conquest ("let it become established as Sichon's city").